# Chrome extension global variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've looked at other global variable questions on Chrome Extension with manifest ver 2, but found nothing.

Assume I have 2 files:

```
// content.js

var myVariable = myVariable(someDiv);
var myVarWithGlobe = VarWithGlobe.fromVariable(myVariable);
```

and

```
// VarWithGlobe.js

var withGlobe = withGlobe || { };

withGlobe.WithGlobe = (function(global) {
    var myLocalVar = global.myVariable;
....

WithGlobe.fromVariable = WithGlobe;
```

both of them are added to **web_accessible_resources, content_scripts** but I can't access global.myVariable in second file since it is undefined.

How can I get it if I'm not allowed to change VarWithGlobe.js?

Answer (score 6):

Content scripts have own execution context (it is even different from the webpage context they are executing in). The only way is to pass messages to/from background page with variable. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740932/disable-enable-chrome-extension-via-browser-action-icon/18788972#18788972) for code samples

Answer (score -6):

In Chromium Version 35.0.1916.114 and probably in all the latest Chrome versions, it is possible to store global variables, while you're testing on the Chrome console.

For example, if you use **console.log()** for a variable in your code, when you see it on your browser console, you can store it by **right clicking on it** and select **"Store as Global Variable"**

I Hope it can help you!